# Error in tag("div", list(...)) : argument "label" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, shiny

I can't find an answer to this error, the best advice I've found was that mainPanel needs to be there even if it is empty. I've emptied it and am still getting this "label" error. Ideas? Thanks in advance

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Oil EUR Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    position="right",
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        "Bin Size",
         min=1,max=1000, value = 100)),
      mainPanel()
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I think you miss the label parameter for the slider input.

Comment: I guess it is evening in your area also...